# Puppeteer can't catch failing request & errors

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I trying to collect data from failing requests and js error.

I'm using the following site: https://nitzani1.wixsite.com/marketing-automation/3rd-page

The site has a request to https://api.fixer.io/1latest, which returns a status code of 404,

also the page contains thw following js error:

```
"Uncaught (in promise) Fetch did not succeed"
```

I've tried to code bellow to catch the 404 and js error but couldn't.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any idea as to how to solve it?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

function wait (ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
}

var  run = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: ['--start-fullscreen']
    });

    page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('error', err=> {
        console.log('err: '+err);
    });

    page.on('pageerror', pageerr=> {
        console.log('pageerr: '+pageerr);
    });

    page.on('requestfailed', err => console.log('requestfailed: '+err));

    collectResponse = [];

    await page.on('requestfailed', rf => {
        console.log('rf: '+rf);
    });

    await page.on('response', response => {
        const url = response.url();
        response.buffer().then(
            b => {
                // console.log(url+' : '+response.status())
            },
            e => {
                console.log('response err');
            }
        );
    });
    await wait(500);

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    await page.goto('https://nitzani1.wixsite.com/marketing-automation/3rd-page', {
    });
};

run();
```

Comment: The target page itself shows me fetch error even without puppeteer. What are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: trying to collect JS errors, requests errors etc..

Comment: Have you found the solution? tried `page.on('console')` with `error` type doesn't work too.

Comment: @otong sorry, had no such luck

Comment: Use `try catch` in your async function.

Answer (score 12):

The complete worked answer is:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const run = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    // Catch all failed requests like 4xx..5xx status codes
    page.on('requestfailed', request => {
        console.log(`url: ${request.url()}, errText: ${request.failure().errorText}, method: ${request.method()}`)
    });
    // Catch console log errors
    page.on("pageerror", err => {
        console.log(`Page error: ${err.toString()}`);
    });
    // Catch all console messages
    page.on('console', msg => {
        console.log('Logger:', msg.type());
        console.log('Logger:', msg.text());
        console.log('Logger:', msg.location());

    });

    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    await page.goto('https://nitzani1.wixsite.com/marketing-automation/3rd-page', { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
    await page.waitFor(10000); // To be sure all exceptions logged and handled
    await browser.close();
};

run();
```

Save in `.js` file and easily run it.

Comment: Note that as of January 2022 `page.waitFor()` is deprecated and the same functionality can be achieved with `page.waitForTimeout(10000);`

Comment: `requestfailed` will NOT catch all failed requests such as 4xx..5xx status codes.
Quote from puppeteer documentation at https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.httprequest - `HTTP Error responses, such as 404 or 503, are still successful responses from HTTP standpoint, so request will complete with requestfinished event.`

Comment: @mohonish complete the answer and provide the fix?

Answer (score -1):

Current puppeteer 8.0.0^ have a very small amount of information in `message.text()`. So we need to get a description of the error from `JSHandle`.
Please check this comment with fully descriptive console errors from `JSHandle` object

Check the link here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801550/9026103