# How Can I Tell If a Background-Image Loaded Successfully ... AFTER The Fact?

Tags: javascript, dom, puppeteer

There are several Stack Overflow questions like [How can I check if a background image is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057990/how-can-i-check-if-a-background-image-is-loaded) which are similar to mine.  They attempt to run code when an element's `background-image` loads, and accomplish this by adding an `onload` handler to the element.

But what if you are running (for instance) a Puppeteer script, which checks the page *after* it has already loaded?  In that case you can't add `onload` handlers.

Is there any way to verify that the `background-image` of an element loaded, "after the fact", without using `onload`?

The only way I can think of is to grab their `background-image` style, then `fetch` the image myself to see if it loads ... but that seems a lot slower than just asking the browser (somehow) if the image loaded ... especially if I'm checking a lot of `background-image`s.

Comment: Have a look at this answer on a similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5058336/16094687

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my description, I can't use a `load`-based solution because Puppeteer is not in control of the page `onLoad`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puppeteer has a config for pages to check the number of idle connections. So the images should be loaded while there are no more requests than specified in 500ms.

```
await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', {"waitUntil" : "networkidle0"});
```

Comment: Thanks, but then if the page doesn't load, how do I know what image was broken?

Comment: You can set a request interceptor and check for requests status and type.
This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52969381/how-can-i-capture-all-network-requests-and-full-response-data-when-loading-a-pag

Comment: Using that technique, how can I tell if an image failed to load?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531779/puppeteer-cant-catch-failing-request-errors. Store the request failures in an array using the `requestfailed` hook. After the page has loaded, loop the DOM nodes checking for a background image src property(computed style). If the background-image src in the request failed array, you know it didn't load.

Comment: I don't see this as the correct answer. "So the images should be loaded while..." - keyword being "should be". This is just checking the page seems to have finished loading everything.

Answer (score 0):

In the *onLoad* event, write away the data you wish to check such that you save state.

Then when your Puppeteer script runs, you will be able to re-inspect the very same data.

Comment: Mixing testing code into production code is generally considered a bad practice.

Comment: True, but I don't think you have many options. Having the puppeteer script see if it can fetch the background image is only testing if the script can do it, not if the page under test actually did it. Why is it worth testing in the first instance, since you can only test that the image loaded at that particular moment (if the image is remote and not on the same server). Testing that the background image loaded is not a guarantee it will always load or that the page is coded correctly. It just indicates the resource was available at the moment the page requested it.