# How to collect errors from page simulated by puppeteer?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, puppeteer

I'm just getting started with puppeteer and creating a test script. I'd like to collect any errors (ideally js errors) the page might produce. This is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true, timeout: 30000, ignoreHTTPSErrors: true});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Navigate to the web page you want to test
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/app/registration', {
    waitUntil: "domcontentloaded",
  });

  // Attach an event listener to capture JavaScript errors
  const errors = await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    const errors = [];
    window.onerror = function (message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
      //errors.push({ message, source, lineno, colno, error });
      errors.push(error);
    };
    return errors;
  });      
  console.log(errors);

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    console.error('JavaScript errors found on the page:');
    errors.forEach((error, index) => {
      console.error(`Error #${index + 1}:`);
      console.error(`  Message: ${error.message}`);
      console.error(`  Source: ${error.source}`);
      console.error(`  Line Number: ${error.lineno}`);
      console.error(`  Column Number: ${error.colno}`);
      console.error(`  Error Object:`, error.error);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('No JavaScript errors found. Page is rendering correctly.');
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

I'm running my react app at localhost:3000 and I've commented out a component import so that my page throws a "ReferenceError: X is not defined." My puppeteer script is resolving to no JS errors. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Also should page.evaluate happen before or after page.goto?

Comment: Are you sure it's an uncaught error, and React isn't catching that error and printing it before it makes it up to trigger `window.onerror`? Maybe a [mcve] of your React script would help. Maybe instead of catching errors like this, try [monitoring error _logs_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075804/6243352) (only logging `if (e.type() === 'error')`). More completely, see [Puppeteer can't catch failing request & errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531779/puppeteer-cant-catch-failing-request-errors/59223836#59223836)

Comment: Also, I would move the `evaluateOnNewDocument` above `goto` so you can be sure it's installed throughout the entire visit.

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for pointing me to  "Puppeteer can't catch failing request & errors" I was surprised to see that window.onerror didn't seem to catch anything even after waiting a few seconds. I had put the same line in my page with a console log and that was firing so I figured it would work through puppeteer but guess not. pag.on("pageerror"... did catch the error I was looking for.